# Amazon RDS PostgreSQL not accepting TCP connections on port 5432

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have created a PostgreSQL Amazon RDS databaes but I cannot connect to it from my local machine.

I am connecting like this:

```
psql -h <db endpoint> -p 5432 -U <username> <db name>
```

Response is:

> Is the server running on host  and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Here are the database settings:

[image: RDS settings]

Here are my security group settings:

[image: Security group inbound rules]

Comment: Pls. move the question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your configuration picture is showing a setting of `Publicly Accessible = No`.

You will need to **modify** your database to set this to `Yes`.

From [Modifying a DB Instance Running the PostgreSQL Database Engine](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyPostgreSQLInstance.html):

> **Publicly Accessible**
>
> Choose **Yes** to give the DB instance a public IP address, meaning that it will be accessible outside the VPC (the DB instance also needs to be in a public subnet in the VPC); otherwise, choose **No**, so the DB instance will only be accessible from inside the VPC.

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to have `Publicly Accessible = Yes` then you should ensure that you've set a `Security Group` which has an `Inbound` rule. You'd have to then ensure that the security group is set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it was the inbound rules on the security group for me!

Comment: Thank you @Trang Pham! In my case I had cloned a CodePipeline but wanted its EC2 instance to connect to a new RDS database. I had forgotten to change the EC2 instance's Security Group to match the one containing the inbound rule on the new db.

Hint - make sure you choose the security group listed under Source for the Inbound Rule, not the security group assigned to the RDS itself!

Comment: You should still have `Publicly Accessible = Yes` if you connect outside of VPC network.  You still can use `Security Group. Inbound rule` to limit ingress connections